# One-way one-to-one relationship with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

What I want to achieve, is have a model `CommentsThread` that can be attached to any other model that needs comments, be it `Chapter`, `BlogPost`, `UserProfile`, or what have you. Basically, the structure I need is

```
CommentsThread
  int ID

Chapter
  int ID
  int Thread FK(CommentsThread.ID)

BlogPost
  int ID
  int Thread FK(CommentsThread.ID)

UserProfile
  int ID
  int Thread FK(CommentsThread.ID)
```

however I have no idea how to configure it properly in EF core, without having to add nullable references to `Chapter`, `BlogPost` and `UserProfile` to the `CommentsThread` model.

My code for `CommentsThread` is as follows:

```cs
public class CommentsThread
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And `Chapter`, omitting any irrelevant properties, is

```cs
public class Chapter
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public CommentsThread CommentsThread { get; set; }
}
```

With the following Fluent config (again, skipping the irrelevant bits):

```cs
builder.Entity<CommentsThread>()
    .HasMany(ct => ct.Comments)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.Entity<Chapter>()
    .HasOne(c => c.CommentsThread)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

On `dotnet ef migrations add X` it throws [this output](https://pastie.io/ehahyz.properties) into the console.

---

**Update:**

So, I tried explicitly adding `public int CommentsThreadId { get; set; }` to the `Chapter` and changing the config to

```
builder.Entity<Chapter>()
    .HasOne(c => c.CommentsThread)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Chapter>(c => c.CommentsThreadId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

That did make the migration go through, but failed on `database update` with

```
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Chapters' and the index name 'IX_Chapters_CommentsThreadId'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: `one-to-one` means both `child-parent` tables have same primary key, but all yours are `one-to-many` by your models code.  what relationship exactly do you need?

Comment: It's not one-to-many. I want one `Chapter` to have exactly one `CommentsThread`, same goes for other models. And I want each `CommentsThread` to belong to exactly one `Chapter`, `BlogPost` or `UserProfile`.

Comment: Your upgrade failed because you didn't allow the thread id to be null for existing rows. Either write a migration step to insert the missing rows, or make the column nullable.

Comment: Could you share your whole model and DbContext?If you share the migration file would be better.

Comment: Seems like it was, indeed, an issue with nullability as @JeremyLakeman said. If you could maybe add it as an answer so I can mark this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database migration error;

```
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Chapters' and the index name 'IX_Chapters_CommentsThreadId'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is due to adding a non-null column to a table that already has data in it. If you want to force a `CommentsThread` to exist for each record type, you'll also need to write a migration script to insert these records for existing data.

Or just change the foreign key column type to `int?` so it will allow nulls.

Comment: @Angius is there any specific reason to avoid using built-in 1-1 implementation: Type Per Type?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are two ways to configure 1-1 relationship:

1. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx
2. https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

the 1st post requires reference from each model. but you mentioned:

> without having to add nullable references

then, only the 2nd concept (Table Per Type) can reach your goal, but the post is too old code to EF Core.

Here are new data models:

```
public class CommentsThread
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ThreadComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

[Table(nameof(Chapter))]
public class Chapter
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CommentsThread))]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public CommentsThread CommentsThread { get; set; }
}
[Table(nameof(BlogPost))]
public class BlogPost
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CommentsThread))]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public CommentsThread CommentsThread { get; set; }
}

[Table(nameof(UserProfile))]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CommentsThread))]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public CommentsThread CommentsThread { get; set; }
}

public class ThreadComment
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public CommentsThread CommentsThread { get; set; }
}
```

Here is sample context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<CommentsThread> CommentsThreads { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ThreadComment> ThreadComments { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>().ToTable(nameof(Chapter));
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().ToTable(nameof(BlogPost));
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().ToTable(nameof(UserProfile));
    }
}
```

Here is generated migration code:

```
public partial class AddCommentsThread : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "CommentsThreads",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_CommentsThreads", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "BlogPost",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Author = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_BlogPost", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_BlogPost_CommentsThreads_Id",
                    column: x => x.Id,
                    principalTable: "CommentsThreads",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Chapter",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Number = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Chapter", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Chapter_CommentsThreads_Id",
                    column: x => x.Id,
                    principalTable: "CommentsThreads",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ThreadComments",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Content = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                CommentsThreadId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ThreadComments", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_ThreadComments_CommentsThreads_CommentsThreadId",
                    column: x => x.CommentsThreadId,
                    principalTable: "CommentsThreads",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserProfile",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Bio = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserProfile", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_UserProfile_CommentsThreads_Id",
                    column: x => x.Id,
                    principalTable: "CommentsThreads",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_ThreadComments_CommentsThreadId",
            table: "ThreadComments",
            column: "CommentsThreadId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "BlogPost");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Chapter");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "ThreadComments");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserProfile");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "CommentsThreads");
    }
}
```

Here is screenshot for result:

[image]